# How can I log the highest and lowest number entered in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't realize what is my mistake, this is how far I got now:

```
x = 1
e = 0
while x <= 50:
    print "Please enter a number (from 1 to 9):"
    b = float(raw_input())
    asd = 0
    if asd == 0:
        h = b
        l = b        
        asd = 1
    if b < l:
        l = b
    elif b > h:
        h = b
    if 1 <= b or b <= 9:
        x = x * b
        print x
    else:
        print "Number is too large or too small."
    e = e + 1

print "You have reached a value over 50."
print "Highest number entered:", h
print "Lowest number entered:", l
print "Entered numbers:", e
```

This is the program's output:

```
Please enter a number (from 1 to 9):
5
5.0
Please enter a number (from 1 to 9):
4
20.0
Please enter a number (from 1 to 9):
5
100.0
You have reached a value over 50.
Highest number entered: 5.0
Lowest number entered: 5.0
Entered numbers: 3
```

Why is the program giving me 5 instead of 4 as lowest number entered and how can I correct that?

Comment: Please don't use one-letter variable names.

Comment: You might find it easier to find the bug if you used variable names that made any sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you go through the loop, you are setting `asd` to `0`, causing the `if` statement below it to execute every single time, so you are always blindly updating `l` with the value the user just entered, which you have named as `b`

Answer (score 1):

You keep resetting `asd` each iteration, you need to set the variables outside the loop, I would use a list and that will enable you to get the min/max and number of valid inputs :

```
nums = [] # hold all nums outside the loop
limit = 1 
while 50 >= limit:
    num = float(raw_input("Please enter a number (from 1 to 9)")
    if 1 <= num <= 9: 
        limit *= num
        nums.append(num) # add all to list
    else:
        print "Number is too large or too small."

print "You have reached a value over 50."
print "Highest number entered:", max(nums) 
print "Lowest number entered:", min(nums)
print "Entered numbers:", len(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun :)

```
def get_float_input(msg="Enter a Number:"):
    while True:
       try:
          return float(raw_input(msg))
       except ValueError:
           print "Invalid Input Please Enter A Float!"

from itertools import takewhile
my_list = sorted(takewhile(lambda val:val < 50,iter(get_float_input,"Y")))
print "You Have Entered A # Greater than 50"
print "Min:",my_list[0]
print "Max:",my_list[-1]
print "Entered %d Numbers"%len(my_list)
```

Comment: It would perhaps be more fun if you explained in what situations you would actually recommend this approach.